# Отправить POST запрос с данные формы (<form>), используя requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

С помощью `Chrome -> F12 -> Networks` узнал что посылает POST запрос на сервер.

Сайт генерит код "user-registration-login-nonce". При попытке войти на сайт, используя requests, не могу войти. Если же вхожу в браузер, добываю собственно код вручную , и шлю его в теле (data) POST запоса, то все работает.

Вопрос: Можно ли как то получить этот код без браузера? Или сымитировать браузер через python3 (от количества header-ов ничего не меняется, проверил), чтобы сайт выдал этот код. Может можно как то добыть код, используя `requests.Session()`, но тогда объясните как.

Вот собственно то, что посылает POST:

```
username:

password: 

user-registration-login-nonce: 951eaa1c33  # <- нужный код

_wp_http_referer: /login-page/

login: Login

redirect:
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Наверное, значение с `user-registration-login-nonce` сервер на странице размещает в каком-нибудь `input` с `hidden`, т.е. загрузите страницу и поищите там значение. Если так и есть, то нужно попарсить сайт, например через `bs4`, чтобы вытащить нужные значения, что в POST передавать. А так, если для парсинга нужно делать несколько действий, то имеет смысл работать с `requests.Session()` -- тот, например, куки может запомнить и передавать в следующих запросах. Или используйте selenium, но он медленнее работает, зато с ним удобнее

Comment: Спасибо, ща попробую.

Comment: Огромное спасибо тебе! Все работает.

Comment: Круто, сделайте, пожалуйста, ответ, в котором покажите как смогли разобраться с этим :)

Comment: @gil9red Спасибо Вам еще раз. Ответ оставил. 

_P.S. Сейчас я понимаю, что оглавление вопроса в корне не верно. Я не имитирую браузер. Я просто извлекаю co страницы данные, которые сервер требует в форме запроса. Вот, тепер не знаю как оглавить вопрос так, чтобы его нашли те, кто не понимают, как и я раньше.

Comment: Пожалуйста, вы молодец, что разобрались :) Поменял тему вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#import requests
#from bs4 import BeauifulSoup 

url = 'https://this/is/my/URL'
our_data = {'key':'value'}
hiden_key = 'user-registration-login-nonce' #Нужно достать значение к этому ключу


#Создем текущюю сессию:
ses = requests.Session()

#Отправляем первый запрос на сервер, чтобы добыть значение:
s_response = ses.post(url, data = our_data)

#Если сервер ответил корректно (status_code == 200), то извлекаем значение:
soup = BeautifulSoup(s_response.text)
hiden_value = soup.find('input', {'id' : hiden_key}).get_attribute_list('value')

#Добавляем пару ключ-значение в форму запроса:
our_data[hiden_key] = hiden_value

#Теперь, когда значение у нас, снова делаем запрос:
s_response = ses.post(url, data = our_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если не очень заморачиваться, то смотреть надо в сторону Chrome HeadLess. В этом режиме хром ничего не показывает, но ведет себя как абсолютно полноценный браузер. Управлять им при этом можно программно.

Comment: Так то я могу и Selenium использовать. А надо, чтобы браузер не открывался. Возможно ли это?

Comment: Надо еще более глубже исследовать этот сайт. Было у меня такое, что вроде бы все уже раскопал, все секреты узнал, а не идет логин и хоть тресни. Оказалось, что в глубине был зарыт еще и web-socket, который очень тихо что-то сайту сообщал. В http-заголовках вроде чисто, а оно вон как - с черного хода общение дополнительное было.